# Настройка Android Development Tools

Tags: android, справка

- Как установить и настроить плагин Eclipse ADT (Android Development Tools)?
- Где скачать ADT плагин для Eclipse?
- Как решить возникающие при установке проблемы?

Comment: А разве его теперь настраивать надо?)

Comment: Это просто перевод справки для новичков, когда они первый раз подключают плагин в Eclipse. Настройка там минимальная.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html отсюда можно скачать настроенный eclipse и новички скорее всего его теперь и скачают. Если честно даже не помню, чтобы таких вопросов было много, чтобы капитанские факи плодить. Может конечно это и нужно

Answer (score 2):

Android предлагает пользовательский плагин для Eclipse IDE, который называется Android Development Tools (ADT). Этот плагин обеспечивает мощную интегрированную среду для разработки программы. Он расширяет возможности Eclipse, что позволяет быстро разрабатывать новые проекты Android, включая создание интерфейса приложения, отладку приложений, а также экспорт подписанных (или нет) пакетов приложений (APKs) для распространения.

Если требуется установить Eclipse, его можно скачать с http://eclipse.org/mobile

**Примечание**. Если предпочтительно работать в различных IDE, не нужно устанавливать Eclipse или ADT. Вместо этого, можно напрямую использовать SDK инструменты для создания и отладки приложений.

**Скачать плагин ADT**

1. Запустить Eclipse, затем выбрать **Help > Install New Software**.
2. Нажать кнопку **Add** в верхнем правом углу.
3. В диалоговом окне Add Repository, который появляется, ввести "ADT Plugin" для Name и следующий URL для Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
4. Нажать **OK**. Если возникли проблемы при получении плагина, попробовать использовать "HTTP" в URL для Location, а не "HTTPS" (HTTPS предпочтительнее из соображений безопасности).
5. В диалоге Available Software, установить флажок рядом с Developer Tools и нажать кнопку **Next**.
6. В следующем окне вы увидите список инструментов для загрузки. Нажать **Next**.
   Прочитать и принять условия лицензионного соглашения, а затем нажать **Finish**.
7. Если появится предупреждение системы безопасности говорящее, что подлинность и достоверность программного обеспечения не может быть установлена, нажать кнопку **OK**.
8. После завершения установки, перезагрузить Eclipse.

**Настройка плагина ADT**

1. После перезапуска Eclipse, необходимо указать расположение каталога Android SDK.
2. В окне “Welcome to Android Development”, которое появляется, выбрать **Use existing SDKs**. Найти и выбрать расположение каталога Android SDK, который был недавно скачан и распакован.
3. Нажать **Next**.

Теперь Eclipse IDE настроена для разработки программ, но нужно добавить последние инструменты платформы SDK и платформу Android для вашей среды. Чтобы получить эти пакеты для SDK, далее читать про добавление платформ и пакетов.

**Решение проблем при установке**

При возникновении проблемы с загрузкой плагина ADT после выполнения шагов выше - несколько советов:

- Если Eclipse не может найти сайт для удаленного обновления, содержащий плагин ADT, попробуйте изменить URL сайта обновления с использованием HTTP, а не HTTPS, то есть установить расположение для удаленного сайта:

  ```
  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
  ```
- Если вы находитесь за межсетевым экраном (например, корпоративным брандмауэром), убедитесь, что вы правильно настроили параметры прокси-сервера в Eclipse. В Eclipse можно настроить прокси информацию из главного меню Eclipse в **Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections**.
- Если все еще не получается использовать Eclipse, чтобы скачать плагин ADT с сайта удаленных обновлений, вы можете загрузить плагин ADT как файл на локальном компьютере и вручную установить его.

  1. Скачать файл-архив плагина ADT (не распаковывать его)
  2. Запустить Eclipse, затем выбрать **Help > Install New Software**.
  3. Нажать кнопку **Add** в верхнем правом углу.
  4. В диалоговом окне Add Repository нажать кнопку **Archive**.
  5. Выбрать загруженный файла ADT-21.1.0.zip и нажать кнопку **OK**.
  6. Ввести для имени "ADT Plugin" и нажать кнопку **OK**.
  7. В диалоге Available Software , установить флажок рядом с Developer Tools и нажать кнопку **Next**.
  8. В следующем окне вы увидите список инструментов для загрузки. Нажать **Next**.
  9. Прочитать и принять условия лицензионного соглашения, а затем нажать **Finish**.
  10. Если появится предупреждение системы безопасности говорящее, что подлинность и достоверность программного обеспечения не может быть установлена, нажать кнопку **OK**.
  11. После завершения установки, перезагрузить Eclipse.

Чтобы обновить плагин, установленный из архива, придется каждый раз выполнять вышеперечисленные действия заново вместо инструкции обновления по умолчанию.

**Другие ошибки установки**

Обратите внимание, что есть функционал ADT, который требует некоторых дополнительных пакетов Eclipse (например, WST). Если вы столкнулись с ошибкой при установке ADT, ваш Eclipse может не включать эти пакеты. Для получения информации о том, как быстро добавить необходимые пакеты для установки Eclipse, читать раздел. про устранение неполадок http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents

**Для пользователей Linux**

Если следующая ошибка возникла при установке ADT Plugin для Eclipse:

> An error occurred during provisioning.
> Cannot connect to keystore.
> JKS

Значит системе не хватает подходящей виртуальной машины Java. Установка Sun Java 6 решит эту проблему, и можно будет переустановить плагин ADT.

---

[Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download).

*Portions of this page are modifications based on work created and shared by the Android Open Source Project and used according to terms described in the Creative Commons 2.5 Attribution License.*